# Make all properties of an interface optional except some such that Typescript still understands it

Tags: typescript

I would like to make all properties of an interface optional but not all. I found [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-make-all-properties-except-one-optional#:%7E:text=To%20make%20all%20of%20the,property%20setting%20it%20to%20required.) post which describes the following util

```
type MakeOptional<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = 
    Omit<Type, Key> & Partial<Type>;
```

Although this util works like a charm, it introduces two Typescript errors in my code

```
interface Employee {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    salary: number;
}

function test(input: MakeOptional<Employee, 'salary'>): Employee {
    const output: Employee = { // <-- ERROR
        id: 1,
        name: 'John Doe',
        ...input
    };

    return output;
}


const data = { salary: 99, name: 'Bar Foo' };
test(data); // <-- ERROR
```

[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgeTMAlgewHZwDYA8AKuBADRQDSEIUEAHsBNgCYDOUSImAZlCZAB8UALwBYAFBQoyALbpgxUhWohhAMigAFOACcM+JUIDckyemxNdPOAGNoAUVlg8mEBGgBvSdPQsAXFDYAK6yAEYQuqZSQXCyEIFswLoWAObR0mz4eiCBIeGR0QC+ZhI8wdi2GDhQTEkAFBZgwcCB8Eio1biETi5uHhQA5Fl4OYOCAJSBva7uXj5QtjhJUJgtza1QM-3QIlDeMb4BUACMZAvSuPGBgwBSmAAW2FAAIpgQg+eHUAB0f00tBYlCQLXQQYDBXTPNbADbFUpLbArFhwYBwUT7KAjHKBACcuIoVwSUEGACE9FAAGKYTCDKBFaJ1YD1FFoibGIA)

The first error is inside the `test` function

```
'id' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.(2783)
input.tsx(14, 5): This spread always overwrites this property.
```

I think using `MakeOptional` Typescript is complete lost now. For example, if I replace it with `Partial` all is fine again ([DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgeTMAlgewHZwDYA8AKuBADRQDSEIUEAHsBNgCYDOUSImAZlCZAB8UALwBYAFBQoyALbpgxUhWohhAMigAFOACcM%20JUIDckyemxNdPOAGNoAUVlg8mEBGgBvSdPQsAXFDYAK6yAEYQuqZSQXCyEIFswLoWAObR0mz4eiCBIeGR0QC%20ZhI8wdi2GDhQTEkAFBZgwcCBOvrohk4ubh4aUJ5QWXg5eaERulBFAJSB3a7uXj5QtjhJUJgtza1Q873QIgPLvgFQAIxkx7HxgQDkAFKYABbYUAAimBC3lzHSAHQApotZYlCTLXQQYDBXSvTbAbbFUqrbDrFhwYBwUQDIbZXS5KAATgJFFwNygtwAQnooAAxTCYW5TaJ1YD1NEY6bGIA)).

For that same reason, I think, I get that second error

```
Property 'id' is missing in type ....
```

This one I can fix, for example

```
test(data as MakeOptional<Employee, 'salary'>);
```

But I'm not sure what to do with the that first error. Is there, for example, an `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript....` that I can use to suppress it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you made `salary` optional in `input`, but `output: Employee` does require a `salary`. And `id` is not optional, yet you don't have that property in `data` leading to the error.

Comment: I think `type MakeOptional<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = Pick<Type, Key> & Partial<Omit<Type, Key>>` would work in your demo. And no, the error you get isn't from eslint so there's no eslint-ignore, ts-ignore but I'd avoid ever using that

Comment: Ah, thats right, I was confused, `salary` is optional, not id :) Thnx @zapl, that did the trick!